# TargetType for routed events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We have `TargetType` for style, so that we can say *please, only buttons*:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    ...
</Style>
```

However, take to example this snippet:

```
<TabControl >
    <TabControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TabControl.SelectionChanged">
            ...
        </EventTrigger>
    </TabControl.Triggers>
    <TabItem>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

We have something (to example, animation) attached to trigger when **TabControl** (it's even specified in xaml, but doing nothing as a fact) `SelectionChanged` event occurs. This, however, will happily occurs when `ListBox` selected item is changed as well.

It's a nature of routed events, because as there is no handler in `ListBox`, it will be routed to its parent. We could simply use code behind

```
private void Stop(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

and attach it to **every child**, like this:

```
 <ListBox SelectionChanged="Stop">
 ...
 </ListBox>
```

However, imagine there are hundreds of children and at some point we decide to animate their parent. Now **we have to go through all children and attach them to bloody event handler**. Right?

No, it's not right. There should be something missing. An ability to specify a *scope* or *type* or anything (make event trigger strict to declaration). Or perhaps some dirty hack. Anyone knows anything like this?

P.S.: tagged as MVVM, because code-behind is not as good if it is possible to avoid it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... You're animating every parent that it has? What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: *We have `TargetType` for `Style`, so that we can say please, only buttons*... that is incorrect. We tell the Framework that the `Style` is of type `Button` so that it can know which properties to expect and whether to alert us to an error or not.

Comment: +1 for finding an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is caused because both `TabControl` and `ListBox` override the [`Selector.SelectionChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I would however agree with you that if (as we have) we specify that we want to use the overridden `TabControl` event, this shouldn't be confused with the `Listbox.SelectionChanged` event as it is. It might even be an idea to leave a bug report on the [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) website.

However, there is one fix that I can think of, but it might not suit you... it really depends on what you are doing when the selection of the `ListBox`es change. What we can do is to add a handler to each `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event and set the `SelectionChangedEventArgs.Handled` property to be `true`, so that it does not interfere with the `SelectionChanged` event of the `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TabControl.SelectionChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0.25" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TabControl.Triggers>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

...

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

If you want to do something when the selection changes on either `ListBox`, then I suggest that you use the `SelectedItem` property to manage that instead and then you won't miss the `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event.